# Exact Confidence Interval for Proportion Estimated with Cluster Sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, references, survey

Can anyone suggest a reference that discusses how to calculate an exact confidence interval (i.e., does not use the normal approximation) for a proportion estimated from a single stage cluster sample with equal cluster sizes?